# java read content from SequenceInputStream issue

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to read content from SequenceInputStream
but it return me null but when i inspect it contains value please refer the screenshot

[image]

following is my code

```
InputStream is = m.getContent(InputStream.class);
SequenceInputStream si = new SequenceInputStream(is, null);
int j;    
int i=0;      
while((i=si.read())!=-1) {    
    System.out.print((char)i);    
}
```

I also tryid to read it from InputStream
but the same output

[image]

follwoing is my input stream read code

```
              CachedOutputStream bos = new CachedOutputStream();

                  IOUtils.copy(is,bos);
                  String soapMessage = new String(bos.getBytes());
                  System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
                  System.out.println("incoming message is " + soapMessage);
                  System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
                  bos.flush();
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `SequenceInputStream` instead of reading from the `InputStream` you already have?

Comment: I don't believe you can pass a `null` argument to the constructor.

Comment: i tried to read InputStream  also but when i inspect it, it contains the same data and output is blank

Comment: @MauricePerry i just update my question with input strem please check

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @MauricePerry i added my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194362/discussion-between-ganesh-gudghe-and-maurice-perry).

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to use two streams should be not null. If anyone of the stream is null you will get null pointer exception after reading the first one.

you change your code to SequenceInputStream si = new SequenceInputStream(null, is); you get NPE at first place

Why you have to use sequenceInputStream to read the content. You can use below code or any other stream reader

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, encoding);
String theString = writer.toString();
```

Thanks,
Gowtham

Comment: I have tried suggestion that you mentioned above but it not work for me.

Comment: What error you are getting ... put the current code